# How to decode the file in Google colab using python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

this is the file that I have to run in google colab but the problem is I can no see the string. it is in encoding I have to decode that file so how can I do that.

**This is the code for fetching file from the google drive.**

```
import urllib.request
    response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L4zhc1Vdpdy78t8CgZgA165siRtNaEsQ/view?usp=sharing')
    html = response.read()
    print(html)
```

**This is the output of my file which i fetch from google drive.**

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="google" content="notranslate"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;"><style nonce="x--bC4aRxWuHAUsRhwmqpQ">@font-face{font-family:\'Roboto\';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xIIzc.ttf)format(\'truetype\');}@font-face{font-family:\'Roboto\';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc9.ttf)format(\'truetype\');}@font-face{font-family:\'Roboto\';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxP.ttf)format(\'truetype\');}@font-face{font-family:\'Roboto\';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc9.ttf)format(\'truetype\');}@font-face{font-family:\'Roboto\';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc9.ttf)format(\'truetype\');}</style><meta name="referrer" content="origin"><title>indian_histpry.txt - Google Drive</title><meta property="og:title" content="indian_histpry.txt"><meta property="og:type" content="article"><meta property="og:site_name" content="Google Docs"></script></body></html>'
```

**How to Decode this encoded file using python?**

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1L4zhc1Vdpdy78t8CgZgA165siRtNaEsQ&export=download')
html = response.read().decode('utf8')
print(html)
```

This works for me

Comment: yes, it works...but which URL that you have used in the code was different, can you please tell me where had you got that URL coz that is different from my URL which I have used.

Comment: This URL appears when you select to download the file on your google drive (rather than open/view or edit it). Also, the structure of this URL is always the same. It is composed like this: First "https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=" then the id of your file, which I got from your URL and then "&export=download".. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1L4zhc1Vdpdy78t8CgZgA165siRtNaEsQ&export=download')
html = response.read()
decoded_text=html.decode('utf8')
print(decoded_text)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works... But the URL that you used is different from my URL pls tell me where you took that URL and if you will use my URL that I used it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L4zhc1Vdpdy78t8CgZgA165siRtNaEsQ/view?usp=sharing')
html = response.read().decode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
print(html)
```

**Update** - This is tested and working

Install the PyDrive wrapper & import libraries.

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
```

import libraries

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
```

Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.

```
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Download a file based on its file ID.

```
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'1L4zhc1Vdpdy78t8CgZgA165siRtNaEsQ'}) # replace the id with id of file you want to access
downloaded.GetContentFile('indian_histpry.txt')
```

Read file content and print

```
with open('indian_histpry.txt', "r") as file1:
    FileContent = file1.readlines()

print(FileContent)
```

Comment: A little explanation  would help people understand what you are trying to do!

Comment: Not working...still same error is there.

Comment: @DilipKukadiya what output are you expecting as I can see different output than yours. 
I see a very very long text in the output.

Comment: yes right, I expected output like your output. can you pls add this [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L4zhc1Vdpdy78t8CgZgA165siRtNaEsQ/view?usp=sharing ] URL and run it in your code bcoz it is not working for me.